# DataGridCell.Template Style overriding IsSelected Trigger

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, styles

Why does the IsSelected Trigger below only work when Template Setter is absent from the code?  How can I get both to function as expected?

I have the following in my Application.Resources tag;

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: it would seem the presence of the Template setter also removes the default blue selection background

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you re-template the DataGridCell you also lose the border that is actually the control that draws the Background. Add this and it'll work.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```